# Create a paypal recurring payment with an initial amount

Tags: c#, .net, paypal

Trying to create Recurring Payments using PayPal and I need to charge an initial payment for membership and then this is recurring every year thereafter.

What I have so far from following the interactive guides is below, although they give you an idea of what to do they lack certain parameters to do what i need it to do.

```
var homepage = UmbracoContext.Current.ContentCache.GetAtRoot().SingleOrDefault(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "Homepage");
var paymentDetail = new PaymentDetailsType();
paymentDetail.PaymentAction = (PaymentActionCodeType)EnumUtils.GetValue("Sale", typeof(PaymentActionCodeType));
paymentDetail.ItemTotal = new BasicAmountType((CurrencyCodeType)EnumUtils.GetValue("GBP", typeof(CurrencyCodeType)), "30.00");
paymentDetail.OrderTotal = new BasicAmountType((CurrencyCodeType)EnumUtils.GetValue("GBP", typeof(CurrencyCodeType)), "30.00");
paymentDetail.OrderTotal.value = "30.00";

var paymentDetails = new List<PaymentDetailsType> { paymentDetail };

//Get default PayPal server settings from our hompage node
var paypalurl = homepage.GetPropertyValue("payPalReturnURL").ToString();
var paypalcancelurl = homepage.GetPropertyValue("payPalCancelURL").ToString();

var ecDetails = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType
{
    ReturnURL = paypalurl,
    CancelURL = paypalcancelurl,
    PaymentDetails = paymentDetails
};

var billingCodeType = (BillingCodeType)EnumUtils.GetValue("RecurringPayments", typeof(BillingCodeType));
var baType = new BillingAgreementDetailsType(billingCodeType)
{
    BillingAgreementDescription = "FLA Associate Membership - Recurring - £30.00",
};
ecDetails.BillingAgreementDetails.Add(baType);

var request = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType
{
    Version = "104.0",
    SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = ecDetails
};

var wrapper = new SetExpressCheckoutReq { SetExpressCheckoutRequest = request };
var sdkConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"mode", homepage.GetPropertyValue("payPalMode").ToString()},
    {"account1.apiUsername", homepage.GetPropertyValue("payPalAPIUsername").ToString()},
    {"account1.apiPassword", homepage.GetPropertyValue("payPalAPIPassword").ToString()},
    {"account1.apiSignature", homepage.GetPropertyValue("payPalAPISignature").ToString()}
};
var service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(sdkConfig);
var setEcResponse = service.SetExpressCheckout(wrapper);

var token = setEcResponse.Token;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
{
    // add user details to session
    Session["FLACurrentuser"] = model;
    var tokenurl = homepage.GetPropertyValue("payPalTokenRedirect").ToString();
    return Redirect(tokenurl + token);
}
else
{
    return Redirect("/register/error.aspx");
}
```

This shows this screen, as you can see no item details here to take initial payment:

[image]

When I accept and continue and get sent to the success page I use this code here to create the recurring payment:

```
var success = Request.QueryString["success"];
var token = Request.QueryString["token"];

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(success) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
{
    var model = Session["FLACurrentuser"] as RegisterAssociateViewModel;
    var homepage = UmbracoContext.Current.ContentCache.GetAtRoot().SingleOrDefault(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "Homepage");

    var createRpProfileRequest = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType();
    var createRpProfileRequestDetails = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType();
    createRpProfileRequestDetails.Token = token;
    createRpProfileRequest.CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails = createRpProfileRequestDetails;

    var profileDetails = new RecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsType();
    profileDetails.BillingStartDate = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'");


    int frequency = 1;
    var paymentAmount = new BasicAmountType((CurrencyCodeType)EnumUtils.GetValue("GBP", typeof(CurrencyCodeType)), "30.00");
    var period = (BillingPeriodType)EnumUtils.GetValue("Year", typeof(BillingPeriodType));
    var paymentPeriod = new BillingPeriodDetailsType(period, frequency, paymentAmount);
    //paymentPeriod.TaxAmount = new BasicAmountType((CurrencyCodeType)EnumUtils.GetValue("GBP", typeof(CurrencyCodeType)), "30.00");

    var scheduleDetails = new ScheduleDetailsType();
    scheduleDetails.Description = "FLA Associate Membership - Recurring - £30.00";
    scheduleDetails.PaymentPeriod = paymentPeriod;

    var activationDetails = new ActivationDetailsType();
    activationDetails.InitialAmount = new BasicAmountType((CurrencyCodeType)EnumUtils.GetValue("GBP", typeof(CurrencyCodeType)), "30.00");

    scheduleDetails.ActivationDetails = activationDetails;

    createRpProfileRequestDetails.RecurringPaymentsProfileDetails = profileDetails;
    createRpProfileRequestDetails.ScheduleDetails = scheduleDetails;


    var createRpProfileReq = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq();
    createRpProfileReq.CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest = createRpProfileRequest;


    var sdkConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    sdkConfig.Add("mode", homepage.GetPropertyValue("payPalMode").ToString());
    sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiUsername", homepage.GetPropertyValue("payPalAPIUsername").ToString());
    sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiPassword", homepage.GetPropertyValue("payPalAPIPassword").ToString());
    sdkConfig.Add("account1.apiSignature", homepage.GetPropertyValue("payPalAPISignature").ToString());
    var service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(sdkConfig);
    var createRpProfileResponse = service.CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile(createRpProfileReq);
```

This creates the recurring payment profile with a initial payment but I'm getting 0 in Amount sent and Amount total?

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Instead of all the code generating your stuff, I just need to see the actual API request that's getting generated as well as the response you're getting back.

Comment: Hi, looking at the sandbox this morning the payments seem to have updated (set to Active) and taken the amount required, seems my code is correct and its PayPal's sandbox that is very slow in updating. By adding an initial payment you effectively charge the user twice, Ive removed the initial payment as the recurring payment is taken on the same day, then the next in a years time once its taken the recurring payment on the same day. Seems an odd way of doing it though.

Comment: The initial payment is a separate payment from the profile.  If you use an initial payment set the start date to the "current day" then yeah, you'll see two transactions on that first day.  The initial payment would, for example, like a setup fee on top of a subscription.  It's just a one-time payment that gets done when the profile is created, but the actual profile payments are separate.